# Add parameter from data-textval to URL after lightbox is opened

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to pass data-textval="value" parameter from an  element to lightbox URL, which comes from SimpleLightbox.js library.

For now, when I fire lightbox, url looks like that:

*domainname.com/category/#pid=1?utm_source=portfolio*

I need to add following parameter *'&utm_content=value'* of an element which is clicked to the URL without refreshing a page.

This is a bit of code I came up with, but it's not working:

```
        $('.lightbox_link').on('click', function (e) {
            var attr = $(this).attr('data-textval');
            var url = '&' + attr;
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("utm_source=portfolio") > -1){
                window.location = $(this).attr('href') + url;
                alert(window.location);
            } else {
                window.location;
            }
        })
```

Is there any easy way to do this with jQuery/ajax ?

Comment: You want to use the [`History API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) ...specifically `history.pushState()` to change url without reloading

Answer (score -1):

you need to assign it to window.location.href, because it contains the url

```
$('.lightbox_link').on('click', function (e) {
            var attr = $(this).attr('data-textval');
            var url = '&' + attr;
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("utm_source=portfolio") > -1){
                window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')+ url;
                alert(window.location.href);
            } else {
                window.location.href;
            }
        })
```

Comment: `window.location = 'urlstring'` does exactly the same thing as `window.location.href = 'urlstring'`, The `else` is doing absolutely nothing